# VisualStudio 2012 external includes visibility

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have "source" and "include" folders which contain .cpp and .h files respectively for my project.
I have them in the same directory as the project.In the project I include the content of both folders and in the properties add the "include" folder as additional include directory.The project compiles but I can't access any header which is not related to these files via intellisense.For example GL\glew.h headers are included and used in my headers but I can't see those in the headers list when typing #include. Once I create a .cpp file outside "include" or "source" folder all the rest of project includes become visible there again.What do I miss here?

Comment: It is pretty unclear, but it sounds to me like you set the Additional Include Directories option to "include" instead of the required "..\include".  With the compiler lucky enough to find them anyway.  No such luck for the IS parser, it doesn't have a default directory.

Comment: @HansPassant seems like this is exactly the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this.Here is what was the issue:

It appears that using realtive path in VS2012 like this:

**../../../SomeIncludeDir**

Wouldn't really work for intellisence .At least for me.
I had to add this in the beginning :

$(ProjectDir)

So it goes like this:

**$(ProjectDir)/../../SomeIncludeDir**

This way VS can see the included dir ok.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set path to the header files in project properties. Adding the headers to the solution explorer does not make them visible to IntelliSense.

Alt+F7 to open Property Pages > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories

Comment: "In the project I include the content of both folders and in the properties add the "include" folder as additional include directory"

Comment: Try to delete the file with extension ***.user** and rebuild the project. If this does not help, test on some independent project that IntelliSense works fine.

Comment: It doesn't work.but if I create a file outside the "source" folder ,in the project root, then I can see the rest of the headers all right.

Comment: What file are you referring to? And what is the "rest" of the headers?

Comment: Let's say I have in "additional includes" headers for boost , glew etc.Once I add "include" folder with my project headers they can't see glew ,boost etc.Intellisense doesn't show them.But if I create a file not in "include" or " source" but in the root of the project , then all the included headers are visible.

Comment: Assuming the "includes" directories are added in the project properties, I am running out of ideas. You may also double check the path of the include directories, sometimes I encountered problem when using relative path as opposed to absolute.